# Multi select from wordpress sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I tried to get posts from wordpress sql, I want get posts where post_type = 'post' and where post_type = 'page'

My code:

```
   $wpdb->get_row( " SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'post' and post_type = 'page' AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY RAND() " );
```

This code is correct

```
$wpdb->get_row( " SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY RAND() " );
```

but only post_type = 'posts' i want both! post and page.

[About Wordpress SQL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not doing a standard `WP_Query()`?

Comment: code is correct but i got post from post_type = 'post'  i want get from both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `OR`:

```
$wpdb->get_row( " SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE (post_type = 'post' OR post_type = 'page') AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY RAND() " );
```

...but I still don't understand why you don't do a standard [`WP_Query()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('post', 'page'),
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: What are you mean about WP_Query?

Comment: Yeah because I make simple widget.

Comment: @Sultan That's not a reason to not use WP_Query - WPDB should be used only for querying custom tables. For querying posts there is already built-in functions that does that pretty well and that return you post objects.